# How to authorize request using cookie in postman

Tags: cookies, request, postman

[image]

If the request in Mozilla looks like this, how can I make this request using postman and python. I couldn't find a way to set cookies in postman and I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

In postman in request tab below Send button, there is an option to Add cookie. If you want to know more about configuring cookie in Postman you can refer here

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/cookies/

[image]